# Gradle .. difference between these two lines

Tags: gradle

I wrote a gradle build file

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang', version: '3:3.0'
```

This gives an error that

```
Could not find org.apache.commons:commons-lang:3:3.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang/3:3.0/commons-lang-3:3.0.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang/3:3.0/commons-lang-3:3.0.jar
```

If I change the dependency line to

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
```

it works!

But my understanding is that both these lines should be identical. Can anyone tell me why does the "group", "name" and "version" syntax does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
```

?

Minor difference, yet critical.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you have a typo here. it should be

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
```